# Is the current video buffer segment address recorded in a memory location?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, bios, vga

By using - for example - an interrupt to change the current page, the segment address of the video buffer will be changed too like after:

```
mov ah, 5
mov al, 1
int 10h
```

For example, I'm now in text mode, the segment of my VGA at page 0 is 0B800h, now after previous interrupt the segment will be 0B900, where it is recorded in memory or we have to calculate it because these addresses are fixed ones?

Comment: That depends on how you access the video memory. If you use the BIOS functions, you specify the page as part of the call.

Comment: I'm planning to program a procedure in Turbo Pascal that will know automatically the current active page segment to type characters directly to it without needing to call an interrupt to know the active page.

Comment: https://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html suggests it might be found in the byte at `40h:62h`.  I haven't tested.

Comment: If you know you are in Text mode already and you know the base of your text video is 0b800h then after doing `mov ah, 5` `mov al, 1` `int 10h`. When you use the BIOS interrupts video info they are reflected in data in the [BDA](https://stanislavs.org/helppc/bios_data_area.html). In particular the word value at 0000:44eh is the byte offset from the start of segment b800h (if in color text mode). You can put the value B800h in ES, copy the word value from 0000:44eh to BX and then write to video memory with `mov word ptr [es:bx], 5661h` to wrte to the upper left hand corner of the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current video buffer **segment address** is not recorded in memory. BIOS doesn't use it that way.

BIOS records this info about pages in the BIOS Data Area

```
                                                              80x25
                                                              -----
word 0040:004C  Size in bytes of the display memory page    = 4000
word 0040:004E  Offset to the current display page          = 4096
byte 0040:0062  Number of the active display page           = 1
```

In the 80x25 text video mode BIOS only deals with the segment value B800h and varies the offset to arrive at the correct output page. BIOS first calculates the offset **within** the requested page, and then adds the word from address 0040:004E.